# Convert ajax calendar value to datetime in textbox blur event using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.net textbox with AJAX calendar extender control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxReceivedDate" CssClass="selectstyle" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Width="200" onblur="parseStringtoDateTime();"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="tbxReceivedDate" Format="ddd MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" runat="server"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

I want to convert this string into a proper date format (ex., 08/17/2014 9:43:00 AM) using JavaScript in `textbox blur` event.

So far, I have below code but it is not giving me the desired result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parseStringtoDateTime() {
        var t = new Date($('#<%= tbxReceivedDate.ClientID %>').val());
        alert(t);
    }
</script>
```

What can I change to get the desired result?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date in javascript through the AJAX behavior, like this:

```
var date = $find("behaviorID").get_selectedDate();
```

For this to work, in your `CalendarExtender` you should define the `BehaviorID` attribute like this `BehaviorID="behaviorID"`

Comment: Thanks. But it returns the date in this format : Thu Aug 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), I want it to return as 08/13/2015 12:00:00 AM. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can use date.toLocaleDateString()

Comment: I used date.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + date.toLocaleTimeString() to return complete datetime value but now when I change only time in the calendar, it still returns 08/13/2015 12:00:00 AM. How do I get the changed time as well?